# NodeJS + AngularJS + File Upload - connect-busboy doesn't call callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

[Sources here](http://lw-scm.de/lipperts-web/nodejs-checkstyle-analyser/tree/master/src)

I try implementing an NodeJS Server taking file-uplods using [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy)  from AngularJS using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) for later Analysis.

My Problem is that the callback `req.busboy.on('file', function (args...){});` will not be called...

So I can't continue developing because I Need the file-Contents :)

Anyone got an Idea?

[Sources here](http://lw-scm.de/lipperts-web/nodejs-checkstyle-analyser/tree/master/src)

Comment: Show us more code please! :)

Comment: Using https://github.com/expressjs/multer with https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload works extremely nice

Comment: @manzapanza there are no more sources than they are at the "sources here"-Link. That is the whole git Project. For first analyses today morning I kicked out angular-file-upload now my callback gets called. But I think the mistake was on the serverside (busboy-handling) so today evening I will implement back angular-file-upload for testing purposes http://lw-scm.de/lipperts-web/nodejs-checkstyle-analyser/commit/e5aac491b41b9df8d317b92b2a431b8f6a33ae5f

Comment: @lippoliv sorry if I didn't see the link, but you should place only the interested code in your question to help us help you :) As Gonzalo Bahamondez said, take a look at http://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload repository. There's a full example angular and server side with node.js

Comment: @manzapanza you are right, sorry. What you may don't know: Currently there is nothing else implemented than that upload-Thing, that is the very Basic of the Project -.- may I will have a look on that, thanks all :) I will post here and mark done, when have a watch tonight

Answer (score 0):

OK after getting deeper into analyses it was an Problem on server-side.

So heres the [first commit](http://lw-scm.de/lipperts-web/nodejs-checkstyle-analyser/commit/e5aac491b41b9df8d317b92b2a431b8f6a33ae5f) removing angular-file-upload and also removing Problem from Server. An here's the [second commit](http://lw-scm.de/lipperts-web/nodejs-checkstyle-analyser/commit/3b997c1ac43cb58ef7e1c69c1cd2d56686e51456) reactivating angular-file-uploader again.

Thanks for all ideas :)